# When are two pointers comparable?

Tags: c++, pointers, type-traits, comparison-operators

There so many questions on comparing two pointers, but I found none on whether the two *types* are such that the pointers can be compared. Given

```
A* a;
B* b;
```

I want to know if expression `a @ b` is valid, where `@` is one of `==`,`!=`,`<`,`<=`,`>`,`>=` (I don't mind about `nullptr_t` or any other type that can be implicitly converted to a pointer). Is it when `A, B` are

- equal?
- equal except for cv-qualification?
- in the same class hierarchy?
- ...?

I didn't find anything in `std::type_traits`. I could always do my own SFINAE test, but I am looking for the rules to apply them directly. I guess that will be easier for the compiler, right?

**EDIT** To clarify again: I am comparing pointers, not objects pointed to. I want to know in advance when `a @ b` will give a compiler error, not what will be its value (true or false or unspecified).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ Standard

## 5.9 Relational operators

> Pointers to objects or functions of the same type (after pointer conversions) can be compared,
>   with a result defined as follows:
>
> — If two pointers p and q of the same type point to the same object or function, or both point one past
>   the end of the same array, or are both null, then p<=q and p>=q both yield true and p<q and p>q both
>   yield false.
>
> — If two pointers p and q of the same type point to different objects that are not members of the same
>   object or elements of the same array or to different functions, or if only one of them is null, the results
>   of pq, p<=q, and p>=q are unspecified.
>
> — If two pointers point to non-static data members of the same object, or to subobjects or array elements
>   of such members, recursively, the pointer to the later declared member compares greater provided the
>   two members have the same access control (Clause 11) and provided their class is not a union.
>
> — If two pointers point to non-static data members of the same object with different access control
>   (Clause 11) the result is unspecified.
>
> — If two pointers point to non-static data members of the same union object, they compare equal (after
>   conversion to void*, if necessary). If two pointers point to elements of the same array or one beyond
>   the end of the array, the pointer to the object with the higher subscript compares higher.
>
> — Other pointer comparisons are unspecified.
>   §

Comment: So: expression `a @ b` will *never* give a compiler error, regardless of whether the result is specified or nor, right?

Comment: Yes; the compiler won't complain.  Undefined behaviour gives it a chance to optimize in non-obvious ways.

Comment: @Jonathan: "Yes, the compiler won't complain" - not true... you can't compare pointers to unrelated types without a compile-time error.  "Undefined behaviour..." - Spook describes *unspecified* behaviour - which basically means the compiler may have put either of the pointed-to-objects at the higher memory address, not *Undefined* which would mean the comparison can't be made without risking crashing or otherwise corrupting the program state.

Comment: "Pointers...of the same type (after pointer conversions) can be compared" +1 for that, but it's half the question, the other half is whether pointers of different types can be compared....

Comment: They must be compatible, i.e. one convertible to the other with standard pointer conversions.

Comment: Ok, the situation becomes so complex that maybe I shouldn't be doing any test in the first place and just let the compiler complain... Or if I do make a test, SFINAE on `decltype(a @ b)` is maybe faster and less error-prone than "encoding" all those rules?

Comment: @Spook It's in order to provide comparison operators for iterators. But I now see in the rules that in fact the two types are not even enough to know whether the compiler will give an error; more information is needed. So I think I shouldn't be doing any test: just define my comparison operator and let the compiler check if the underlying pointers can be compared. Maybe it was a dumb question after all.

Comment: @Spook/@n.m. By the way, what are the "standard pointer conversions"?

Comment: @iavr There are several sections in the C++ standard regarding this matter. Here you can get almost-recent-C++11 standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Those comparison operators are always 'valid', in that you can always use them. But the results usually will not be meaningful or useful.

`==` and `!=` will essentially tell you whether or not `a` and `b` refer to the same object. If `a == b`, then changing *a will affect *b and vice-versa.

`>`, `<`, `>=`, and `<=` will tell you where the memory addresses are, relative to one another. Usually this information will be irrelevant to the functionality of your program, and in most cases it will be unpredictable. However, one example that comes to mind where you might be able to use it is if you know that `a` and `b` point to member of the same array. In which case `a < b` will tell you whether or not the object `*a` comes before `*b` in the array.

Comment: "Those comparison operators are always 'valid', in that you can always use them." - that's not true... you can't compare an `A*` to a `B*` when `A` and `B` are unrelated types... you'll get a compiler error.