# The Function std::max() C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, max, codeblocks, string-literals

I was trying the function `max()` using **visual-studio 2022 Version 17.7.1**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << max("5", "4") << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and the Output is :

```
4
```

and when I change the code to :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << max("4","5") << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

the Output is :

```
5
```

but when I am using **codeblocks** :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << max("5", "4") << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and the Output is :

```
5
```

and when I change the code to :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << max("4","5") << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

the Output is :

```
4
```

So visual-studio 2022 Version 17.7.1 choose the second parameter every time and codeblocks choose the first parameter every time ( I guess that ) but Why ? is that because the parameters is converted to `const char*` so the comparison every time ( in both visual-studio 2022 Version 17.7.1 and codeblocks ) is between two pointers so it is between two addresses ?

Comment: You can’t compare strings like that

Comment: You are comparing pointers to string literals, not the actual integer values represented in those strings. It is undefined behavior to compare pointers for two disparate objects. Use `std::stoi` or `std::strtol` if you want to parse a string as an integer.

Comment: Related: [When are two pointers comparable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22471909/11082165), [Is it unspecified behavior to compare pointers to different arrays for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4909766/11082165)

Comment: Try explicitly writing `("4" < "5")` instead and see the warnings your compiler gives you. See also [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/11082165)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen that's not UB. The result is arbitrary but it isn't UB.

Comment: @ALX23z Hmm. I thought comparing pointers not from the same array is always UB. I stand corrected.

Comment: Try `cout << max("5"s, "4"s) << "\n";` for better results — to compare **strings** rather than **pointers**.  You'll need `using namespace std::literals::string_literals;`.

Comment: in this code : `cout << max("5"s, "4"s) << "\n";`  `"4"` and `"5"` are converted to `string` because of  the `s operator` so this code : `cout << max("5"s, "4"s) << "\n";` is equivalent to this code : `string j="5"; string k="4"; cout << max(j,k) << "\n";` , right ? @Eljay

Comment: That is correct.  And `std::string` objects have intuitive behavior, whereas C-style C-string literal char arrays do not have beginner programmer friendly behavior (and I don't think their behavior is very friendly for seasoned programmers either).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your calls of `std::max` there are compared addresses of string literals. The result of such a comparison in C++ is unspecified (in C it is undefined behavior).

From the C++20 Standard (7.6.9 Relational operators)

> 1. ...The lvalue-to-rvalue (7.3.2), array-to-pointer (7.3.3), and
>    function-to-pointer (7.3.4) standard conversions are performed on the
>    operands. **The comparison is deprecated if both operands were of array
>    type prior to these conversions (D.5)**.
>
> 4 The result of comparing unequal pointers to objects81 is defined in
> terms of a partial order consistent with the following rules:
>
> (4.1) — If two pointers point to different elements of the same array,
> or to subobjects thereof, the pointer to the element with the higher
> subscript is required to compare greater.
>
> (4.2) — If two pointers point to different non-static data members of
> the same object, or to subobjects of such members, recursively, the
> pointer to the later declared member is required to compare greater
> provided the two members have the same access control (11.9), neither
> member is a subobject of zero size, and their class is not a union.
>
> (4.3) — **Otherwise, neither pointer is required to compare greater than
> the other**

Instead you should write

```
#include <cstring>

//...

std::cout << std::max( "5", "4", []( const auto &s1, const auto &s2 ) { return std::strcmp( s1, s2 ) < 0; } ) << "\n";
std::cout << std::max( "4", "5", []( const auto &s1, const auto &s2 ) { return std::strcmp( s1, s2 ) < 0; } ) << "\n";
```

in this case the output will be

```
5
5
```

That is to compare two strings you need to use standard string function `strcmp` declared in header `<cstring>`.

Comment: ٍSo My Code ( in My question ) in C++ is unspecified (in C it is undefined behavior) because the parameters ( `"5"` and `"4"` ) is converted to `const char*` so the comparison every time ( in both visual-studio 2022 Version 17.7.1 and codeblocks ) is between two pointers so it is between two addresses , right ?

Comment: @f877576 You are right. Relational operators are not defined for arrays. Thus arrays in such operations are converted to pointers to their first elements.

Comment: Another possibility: Go straight to `std::string` where the comparison is what you would expect. But before you go and use this alternative, look at this: [Vlad's solution](https://godbolt.org/z/3fecrjYYh) the compiler can optimize down to constants and then out. The [`string` solution](https://godbolt.org/z/cnrjsEcEs)... No such luck. Compilers am smart, but not this smart. Yet.

Comment: @user4581301: `std::string_view` is better alternative than `std::string` and optimize well [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sTYYM1Y97).

Comment: @Jarod42 Huh. Missed the memo about `stringview` literals. Yes, that's the best of both worlds.